# S3 "GetBucketLocation" REST API Returning Incomplete Results

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using this [AWS provided C# code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html) to test programmatic access to S3. I then referenced this [AWS "GetBucketLocation" REST API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetBucketLocation.html) to make a GET request for my bucket:

`https://poochydev-badstuff-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?location`

My request was successful (HTTP 200/OK), but the response body contained the following useless information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LocationConstraint xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"/>
```

It doesn't matter where the bucket actually resides (us-east-1, us-east-2, us-west-2, etc)...it always gives this response. What am I doing wrong?  According to the documentation, I should instead see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetBucketLocationOutput>
   <LocationConstraint>string</LocationConstraint>
</GetBucketLocationOutput>
```

The `string` would be something like "us-east-1" or "us-west-2".

I see the following [JavaScript AWS SDK issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/590) from 2015 that is almost the same problem I have.  The issue suggests that the response looks identical to my response if the bucket belongs to the us-east-1 region.  But as I said, I'm experimenting with buckets from a number of different regions...and they all give the same response you see above.

Any clues?